# UITableView: how to magnify selected section index letter on the right side section index?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, sections

I cannot remember exactly, but I remember one app some time ago where section letters (A, B, C, D...) seen in section index (at the right side), were magnified, as the user tapped and scrolled on the index. Check this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) for blue letters seen at the right side. For example, if user taps on letter E in section index then this letter is magnified and becomes larger than the others. Also the  two other letters (D and F) at the side are also magnified but a little bit less. So the user can see what section index letter he is currently holding. I'm searching and trying to find how to enable this feature (section index height or smth), but unable to find it. Could someone recap that?

Here's some sketch that describes the idea:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that is something you can enable. That looks like a custom scrollview to me.

But luckily I have starred this on github sometime ago so I guess this is something very similar what you have requested

https://github.com/matthewfx/MJNIndexView